# UIScrollView not working in IB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I have a UIScrollView that contains a UIView inside.

The UIScrollView has paging enabled and is 320x500

The UIView is 320x480

My UIView doesn't scroll in the simulator or on the device. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably didn't set the `contentSize` property of the `UIScrollView`, which is a `CGSize`.
Set this property with the content view frame's size.

Also your `UIView` isn't larger than the scroll view, but it should at least bounce the scroll.

Answer (score 9):

To make the `UIScrollView` scroll, the `ScrollView.contentSize` should be larger than the `ScrollView.frame.size`

If you want it to scroll only up-down, make the `ScrollView.contentSize.height` greater than the `ScrollView.frame.size.height` (and so on for scrolling sideways or both ways)

You'll  have to set the content size programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an object to be the UIScrollView's delegate, and that it implements the required methods for panning. Read more about it here:

[UIScrollView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Hope that helped!